# Preserving spaces in pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I want to implement a format in which one space between letters acts as a marker and only two or more spaces are interpreted as a space. E.g.

```
ab_cdef]   -> abCDEF   //(space as underline for clarity)
ab__cdef]  -> ab CDEF
ab___cdef] -> ab CDEF
```

`' '` and `']'` mark what is to be capitalized and all additional spaces are redued to one visible space in the output.

But pandoc seems to already collapse several spaces to one:

```
$ echo "a a"  | pandoc  -t native
[Para [Str "a",Space,Str "a"]]
$ echo "a  a" | pandoc  -t native
[Para [Str "a",Space,Str "a"]]
```

Is there a way to tell pandoc to parse a `space` for every `' '`?

**Progress:**
These guys talk about it a little: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2741

Comment: you can probably write a [pandoc filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) that does that...

Comment: @mb21 not if pandoc keeps collapsing my spaces, do you know how to suppress that?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I was going for a lua filter, but have no idea where to start

Comment: @Ratnanil I could not make pandoc preserve space. I ended up requiring nonbreaking space or underscores instead of regular space in the input.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the parsing of spaces. The reason is that handling of spaces is entangled with the creation of pandoc's internal document structure. See the code to [concatenate inline elements in `Text.Pandoc.Builder`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Builder.hs#L204). What this means for you is that the spacing information is discarded at a fundamental level, with no way to work around this.

Your best bet is to use a pre-processor of sorts to convert your custom syntax into something that pandoc can deal with.

Comment: Can you you elaborate on what kind of preprocessor you would use?

Comment: Something like `sed -e 's/  /  /g'`, replacing two consecutive spaces with one space and a no-break space.